# How to "round" the range lines in ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, graph, time-series

I am using the following R code to propose a new plot design for work. It would be nice if I can round out the ends of the red bars on this plot. I think I am supposed to use lineend = "round" somewhere but I can't get it to work. (Current plot attached below).

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create the Heart Rate data.
df2 <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(25:110,24,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(df2) <- c("d1","d2","d3","d4","d5")
df2$hour=1:24
df2$min <- apply(df2[,1:5], 1, FUN=min)
df2$max <- apply(df2[,1:5], 1, FUN=max)
df2$mean <- apply(df2[,1:5], 1, FUN=mean)

q <- ggplot(df2, aes(hour, mean, colour = "red"))

#q + geom_linerange(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max)) # Without the mean points

q + geom_linerange(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max, size = 4)) + 
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black",
                                    colour = "black",
                                    size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'dashed',
                                    colour = "gray"), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 1, linetype = 'solid',
                                    colour = "black")
  ) +
  geom_point(colour = "white", size =2)
```

[image: Range and means of repeated measures over time]

Comment: I think you could use `geom_segment()` with the option `lineend` set to "round". Let me know if you need help with that. Official documentation here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in that you need to use the `lineend="round"` argument.  As you have likely noticed, that's not an acceptable argument to use with `geom_linerange()`.  As suggested, you can instead plot your line ranges using `geom_segment()`, which can accept the `lineend=` argument.

The [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html) indicates that `geom_segment()` will draw lines by connecting two points:  `x`,`y` and `xend`,`yend`.  for the vertical lineranges, `x` and `xend` would be the same, while `y` and `yend` would correspond to your `ymin` and `ymax` values used in the `geom_linerange()` code.

To get the round lines, make the following change:

```
# substitute this:
# q + geom_linerange(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max, size = 4)) +

# with this:

q + geom_segment(
  aes(x=hour, xend=hour, y=min, yend=max),
  size=4, lineend='round'
  ) +
```

[image]

One final note:  I noticed the chart you shared had two legends, including one for color and one for size.  I presume you did not want the legend for `size` to appear there.  `ggplot2` creates a legend when you have an aesthetic inside `aes()`.  Notice that in `geom_segment()`, I moved `size=4` to be *outside* `aes()`.  Consequently, the legend for size was not created.

Comment: This solution woks great for this case. A problem arises if you need to jitter or position_dodge (at least I can't find a solution). The geoms do not remain parallel under dodging.